# Is a C++11 mutex compatible with threads NOT created with C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, pthreads

I'm learning C++11 and have run into a threading issue.  My general question: are C++11 mutexes compatible with threads not created with C++11's standard libraries?

I would like to safely share information between a thread created with C++11 and another thread created by a third-party library that I have no control over.

For example, my application uses PortAudio, which creates its own thread for audio output.  I'm not sure if it's using pthreads, or OS-specific threading libraries, but I do know that PortAudio is NOT written in C++11.  I want to safely share data between a GUI thread (using a C++11 thread) and the PortAudio thread using a mutex.

Similarly, can I use a C++11 mutex to synchronize QT QThreads and C++11 threads?

Comment: Er, what mutex are the other bits of code using? You cannot expect to protect a single resource with multiple distinct mutexes. Has to be just the one mutex.

Comment: The intention is to use a single mutex across different types of threads.

Comment: The standard won't help you since you are using implementation specific threads. But for sure, on any platform that runs these libraries, the mutex will work fine on any thread.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify: how can I safely synchronize threads created using different libraries (C++11, QT, pthreads, etc...)?

Comment: What shared resource are all these threads able to access?

Comment: A pthread mutex will work with C++ threads, and vice versa. But the standard won't tell you that.

Comment: @AlanStokes: I have musical note data that needs to be read by the audio-creation thread, and will be read and modified on the GUI thread.  I haven't settled on QT for a GUI, but I hate to think I would be tied to QMutex for the rest of eternity if I do.

Comment: If you can get same mutex (like, some library provides way to access the underlying mutex as C++11 mutex, or can wrap a C++11 mutex provided by you), then same mutex is same mutex. If not, then different mutex is different mutex.

Comment: Your audio library should provive API to do what is needed without exposing internel details like mutexes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The standard only seems to define synchronization in terms of the standard library synchronization primitives. That would seem to mean pthread locking is UB in c++11. Or am I reading the standard wrong? I think any decent implementation SHOULD handle it correctly though.

Comment: @Tim It won't be UB. It will be implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: @DavidHEffernan ok, that is much better then. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I think it is legitimate to call it undefined behavior, though (not that it matters because in practice it's just the same OS primitives anyway). But from a pedantic standard point of view, it is _implementation-defined_ how a compiler implements threads and mutexes or how they interact with each other as long as they fulfill the requirements, but it is _undefined_ how they interact with something else. It is probably legitimate to implement N:1 threads with fibers and a user-level scheduler and custom mutex implementation (not very useful but legitimate). Or M:N threads.

Comment: @Damon Undefined Behaviour, UB, has a specific meaning in the standard. I'm sure this isn't UB.

Comment: @Damon in this case it means the implementation can decide if pthread synchronization protects against race conditions or not. If it was UB, the standard says all bets are off and the compiler doesn't even have to accept your program.

Comment: @Tim: If I search my PDF copy of the standard for "pthread", it reports no matches. None of the "mutex requirements" talk of anything but "thread", which is a _C++ thread_. None of "thread" talks about mutex (C++ or native) at all. The standard does say that "some classes" (these are `thread` and `mutex`) have a `native_handle` function which returns something inherently non-portable implementation-defined, and you should not use it -- it does not require that `native_handle` returns anything meaningful at all. Insofar, from a purely pedantic lawyer PoV, I'd say indeed _all bets are off_.

Comment: @Tim: Of course no implementation will reasonably do anything but use the thread and mutext primitives provided by the OS (it would be pretty insane to do something different). So in practice, I would bet my right arm that it will always "work" anyway. But still, it's undefined behaviour. Not because the standard explicitly states it being UB as per the standard's special meaning, but by the mere fact that it _is undefined_ and you strictly have no clue what's going on under the hood. In theory, all C++ threads _might_ run in one hardware thread, and using a native mutex might deadlock.

Comment: @Damon The relevant text in the standard is "The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conﬂicting actions in diﬀerent threads,
at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other" Since the implementation is free to guarantee ordering properties for pthread mutexes, it is possible for them to not be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Damon and I think you are missing the point, the discussion with David was about the standard's definition of undefined. If you aren't talking about that, then what you say isn't really relevant to my original comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, the C++ standard doesn't make any guarantees about compatebility with other systems. Part of the reason the C and C++ standards added threading facilities was to standardize on one threading system.

In practice it is expected that the C and C++ threads library is built to integrate with a platform threading system if there is one. For example, on platforms using pthreads the expectation is that pthreads are used where appropriate to buildtge standard library threading facilities (as far as I know there is no pthreads interface for the various atomic operations, i.e., the standard library may need to provide its own synchronization primitives).

The standard library classes provide access to the underlying representation through the `native_handle()` methods. A standard library should implement what is returned from these and, e.g., if pthreads types are provided it seems safe to assume that this particular standard library will play nice with pthreads.

Comment: Note, however, that `native_handle` is not required to exist, and if it does exist, its return type is implementation defined. In short: highly non-portable.

Answer (score 9):

> Are C++11 mutexes compatible with threads not created with C++11's standard libraries?

The C++ standard does not define a "thread" as something exclusively created by the C++ standard library.

> 1.10 Multi-threaded executions and data races [intro.multithread]
>
> 1 A thread of execution (also known as a thread) is a single flow of
> control within a program, including the initial invocation of a
> specific top-level function, and recursively including every function
> invocation subsequently executed by the thread.

So, I would conclude the answer to your question is "yes".

Answer (score 3):

The C++11 standard specifies that mutexes should work with any kind of 'execution agent', including different thread libraries. Here are some relevant quotes from the standard which I think answer the question conclusively:

**Mutex requirements**

> A mutex object facilitates protection against data races and allows
>   safe synchronization of data between execution agents (30.2.5). An
>   execution agent owns a mutex from the time it successfully calls one
>   of the lock functions until it calls unlock.

**Requirements for Lockable types**

> An execution agent is an entity such as a thread that may perform work
>   in parallel with other execution agents. [Note: Implementations or
>   users may introduce other kinds of agents such as processes or
>   thread-pool tasks. —end note ] The calling agent is determined by
>   context, e.g. the calling thread that contains the call, and so on.

Comment: That's the definition of the `Mutex` concept. That is, any object with a mutex-y interface. It says does not mean `std::mutex` supports any kind of execution agent. (It does not)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yeah? What kind of execution agent does std::mutex not work with?

Comment: Seriously, can you give one concrete example of when std::mutex does not work as expected? I'd like to test it. Because at the moment I just don't believe you. (But I'm open to being convinced.)

Comment: Try to use it with some kind of green threads. `std::mutex` always blocks physical threads. It doesn't know about any other similar mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

It is inconceivable that C++11's threading implementation will be incompatible with the platform's native threading implementation because any practical program using C++11 threads is going to call into platform libraries, and those libraries may themselves be threaded or make thread related calls (to mutexes for example).

The C++11 library implementation for threads is not of course obliged to use the high level native threading library (say, pthreads or windows threads) but it probably will, for which purpose as has been mentioned there is a std::thread::native_handle() method to get the native handle.  However, even where it does not use the high level native implementation, it will have to use the same low level kernel primitives underneath.

In all conceivable circumstances it should therefore be perfectly safe to use C++11 mutexes with thread instances created by native library calls, and vice versa, and mix any other native or C++ library synchronization calls.  There may indeed be cases where it is necessary to do so.  For example, the C++11 library does not at present provide thread pools or read-write locks (shared mutexes).  You might want to use native read-write locks with threads started using std::thread, or use one of the many thread pool implementations provided by third party libraries in your C++ program.

The only caveat to observe is that trying to mix C++11 threads (which will in practice be obliged to use kernel threads in one way or another for the reasons mentioned above) with thread libraries which do not use kernel threads at all (for example, libraries based on green threads or "user" threads), is likely to lead you into trouble.

Edit: In support of this I notice that §30.3 of C++11 states, albeit non-normatively, that "These threads [std::thread threads] are intended to map one-to-one with operating system threads".